# If $T^k = Id$ for $k\ge 1$ then $T$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, jordan-normal-form

> Let $V$ a finite dimension space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $T:V\to V$, a linear transformation such that $T^k = Id$ for $k\ge 1$. Prove that $T$ is diagonalizable.

I'd be glad for an hint. How do I approach this question?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you already studied Jordan's Canonical Forms?

Comment: Diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Yes, although I'm not sure this assignment is related to this subject, but yes.

Comment: @GitGud, Actually yes. How did you figure it out? Anyway, let me edit the question.

Comment: @AlonAlon JNF helps immensely here. How did I figure it out? It would be false over the real numbers, take for instance $T=[i]$ and $k=4$.

Comment: Assuming that you are working over $\Bbb{C}$ then the duplicate from yesterday covers this (learn to look for dups, please). If not, the claim is false, so it is not too presumptious to think that you are working over $\Bbb{C}$ :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

1) The operator $\;T\;$ is regular (i.e., $\;\det T\neq 0\iff $ all its eigenvalues are non-zero)

2) Suppose $\;\lambda\neq 0\; $ , then over a field of characteristic $\;\neq 2\;$ (which contains all the eigenvalues of $\;T\;$ , say $\;\Bbb C\;$ )

$$\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&1&0\ldots&0\\
0&\lambda&\ldots&\ldots\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda^2&2\lambda&0\ldots&0\\
0&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\end{pmatrix}$$

3) Deduce that $\;T\;$ **has** to be diagonalizable